# Find ID does not find the id and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a 2 views that I want to use before the create action.

1st view is add_sample_details.html.erb

```
<% form_tag add_expt_details_samples_path :method => :post do %>
    <% for sample in @samples %>
        <% fields_for "samples[]", sample do |form| %>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sample Name: <%= sample.name %></legend>
                <p><center><%= form.label :sample_title %>
                <%= form.text_field :sample_title, :size => 25 %></center></p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= form.label :taxon_id %>
                            <%= form.text_field :taxon_id, :size => 15 %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= form.label :scientific_name %>
                            <%= form.text_field :scientific_name, :size => 20 %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= form.label :common_name %>
                            <%= form.text_field :common_name, :size => 15 %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p>
                    <center>
                        <%= form.label :sample_descripition %><br \>
                        <%= form.text_area :description %>
                    </center>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <p><center><%= submit_tag "Next" %></center></p>

    <% for samp in @samples %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag("sample_ids[]", samp.id) %>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

in the SamplesController, the add_expt_details looks like this

```
def add_expt_details
    # Collect the samples that were sent
    @expt_samples = Sample.find(params[:sample_ids])
  end
```

and the add_expt_details.html.erb looks like this

```
<% form_for @expt_samples, :url => create_study_samples_path, :html => { :method => :put }  do |f| %>
    <% @expt_samples.each do |samp|%>
        <% f.fields_for :expts do |form| %>
        <%= form.label :experiment_title  %>
        <%= form.text_field :expt_title, :size => 15 %><br \>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <p><center><%= submit_tag "Next" %></center></p>
<% end %>
```

and my create_study action is like this

```
def create_study
     @study = Study.new(params[:study])
     # this method collects all the samples from the add_sra_details view from the hidden_field_tag   
     if current_user.id?
       # Put the current user_id in the study.user_id
        @study.user_id = current_user.id       
       if @study.save # Save the values for the study  
          # Update the Sample attributes 
          @samples = Sample.update(params[:samples].keys, params[:samples].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
           # For all those sample_ids selected by the user, put the study ids in the sample_study_id
           @samples.each do |samp|     
             @study.samples << samp        
           end       

           # get the ids_sent from the add_expt_details
            @expt_samples = Sample.find(params[:id])             

           # A Flash message stating the details would be prefereable..! (Means you have to do it)
           flash[:success] = "Your Study has been Created"           
           redirect_to add_expt_details_samples_path
       else
           flash[:error] = "Study Faulty" 
           render :action => "add_sra_details"
       end
     end
  end
```

The error message I get when I keep the @expt_samples = Sample.find(params[:id]) is "undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass"

and If I dont have the @expt_samples, it gives me an error "Couldn't Find id in Sample"

Can some one suggest how can I update set of sample ids from one form and also create new Expt model records that are associated to the sample_ids in another form.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to Rails' [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

To see how to link existing objects with forms, you can see examples here:

http://josemota.net/2010/11/rails-3-has_many-through-checkboxes/

[rails 3 has_many :through Form with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054633/rails-3-has-many-through-form-with-checkboxes)

[has_many through checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352554/has-many-through-checkboxes)

Comment: Hi zsquare, What I actually want is to allow the user to select his  already submitted Samples through a check box. Then using those samples_ids, I want to create an individual Study model (fields), while updating some attributes of the sample models through sample_fields. The accepts_nested_attributes_for  allows me to create new samples with ids which I do not require, I want it to  create a new Study model with fields and provide me fields for the sample_ids that the user selects so that I could associate a new Study model with existing selected samples. I hope I described it clearly.

Comment: You are a savior zsquare. Application works like charm. Cheers